# Why isn't the Bisigi PPA working in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The PPA doesn't support Oneiric yet.

Try to find an alternative that has support for Oneiric, contact the owner and ask if he/she could add support for Oneiric or just drop the PPA.

Answer (score 0):

The bisigi themes PPA only supports Ubuntu up to 11.04, so it will not work in 11.10, because there are no packages available for 11.10 (as yet). It is also unlikely that the developers will support it, according to what they have said about Unity.